# Всем доброго времени суток, есть проблема связанная с установкой Visual Studio Community 2019

Tags: visual-studio

При открытии самого инсталлера во вкладке "доступно" имеется 3 программы vs, в том числе и нужная мне vs community 2019. Проблема в том, что инсталлер думает что я хочу установить vs 2022, которая не поддерживается моей ОС. И при переходе по ссылке перекидывает меня на документацию "Требования к системе семейства продуктов Visual Studio 2022", хотя я пытаюсь установить 2019. Буду благодарен если кто подскажет в чем может заключатся проблема. Ниже прикрепил пару фото для понимания проблемы.
[image]

[image]

Comment: Так он же пишет, что и версию 2019 на вашу ОС не сможет установить. А документация просто выведена в первую очередь для самой актуальной версии. Попроьуйте в поиске найти документацию по установке 2019-ой версии.

Comment: Вот требования к Visual Studio 2019 [ссылка](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/visualstudio/releases/2019/system-requirements). Ваша система удовлетворяет их?

Comment: Благодарю за ваши ответы, действительно, моя система не подошла по требованиям vs 2019.